# Spring Boot - How can I pass custom values in HTTP Post api?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, http-post, spring-restcontroller

I'm new with Spring Boot and I have difficult to understand how can I pass data. For example:

I want pass those data to my server:

```
{
    "code", 1,
    "name": "C01"
}
```

So I have create **always** a custom Object with code and name as attributes to have this http post api?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/new/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> createOrder(@RequestBody CustomObject customObject){
    ...
}
```

Another solution I see that can be this but I can't pass numbers (int code), right?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/new/{code}/{name}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createOrder(@PathVariable("code") int code, @PathVariable("name") String name) {
        ...
}
```

Kind regards :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `code` and `name` as `PathVariable`s just like in your example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/new/{code}/{name}")
public ResponseEntity<?> createOrder(@PathVariable("code") int code, @PathVariable("name") String name) {
    ...
}
```

A `PathVariable` can be an int or a String or a long or a Date, according to the docs:

> A @PathVariable argument can be of any simple type such as int, long, Date, etc. Spring automatically converts to the appropriate type or throws a TypeMismatchException if it fails to do so.

You could also define a `PathVariable` of type `Map<String, Object>` like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/new/{code}/{name}")
public ResponseEntity<?> createOrder(@PathVariable("map") Map<String, Object> map) {
    Integer code = (Integer) map.get("code");
    String name = (String) map.get("name");
    ...
}
```

You could even use `@RequestParam` and supply the data in the form of URL query parameters.

So, there are numerous ways in which data can be passed to a Spring MVC controller (more details [in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)) but I think the convention for **posting** complex data (by "complex" I mean more than a single piece of state) is to define a request body which contains a serialised form of that complex state i.e. what you showed in the first example in your queston:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/new/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> createOrder(@RequestBody CustomObject customObject){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks... so if I want use Map<String, Object> I have to pass a JSON object? Like { "code", 1, "name": "C01"}? Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, that's possible but just to reiterate: "the convention for posting complex data (by "complex" I mean more than a single piece of state) is to define a request body which contains a serialised form of that complex state" this is especially the case in REST APIs since that complex state would often be represented by an entity (i.e. a class) on the server side. So, I think your original approach of defining a custom object is more common than posting a `Map`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If this question is about RESTful best practice, since you are developing webservice for creating an Order object, this is how I would design it

### Order.java

```
public class Order {

  private Integer code;
  private String name;

  public Integer getCode() {
    return code;
  }

  public void setCode(final Integer code) {
    this.code = code;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

### Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/orders", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public ResponseEntity<Order> createOrder(@Valid @RequestBody Order order){
    ...
}
```

Technically, you can do many things to achieve the same thing, but that will not be a RESTful service, it will be an RPC at best.

Comment: Hi, thanks but if code is for the Order and name is for the Client, I have a create this new object (with code and name) to pass those data (without usign @PathVariable)? Thanks again

Comment: @Hazlo8 Can you explain a bit more about your requirement